# What are the floating dots?

Tags: pokemon-go

What are the floating dots that look like fireflies? Several of them are pictured in the screenshot below.

There are [observations](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4t3cxd/i_think_the_little_white_dots_around_you_show_you/) that the fireflies change their flight pattern when Pokémon are selected to be tracked. Is there something to it or are they merely cosmetic?

[image: Fireflies]

Comment: The observations are from one removed redditaccount.  Plus the entire thing is from way back when you still track Pokémon. Which was removed from the game weeks ago.

Comment: In Niantic's other game, Ingress, these "fireflies" have a specific meaning. But unless the firefly density changes from location to location, it's probably only cosmetic in Pokemon Go

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having looked at the observation, made by one person on a reddit thread, it seems that the "fireflies" have no use, and are almost certainly only cosmetic.